# Running a command inside a lxc container using C

Tags: c, lxc

'm trying to use the lxc C API to execute a command inside a container, and hopefully later make it to also prints the results of the command on the stdout/stderr. But so far, I can't get further than creating a simple file in `/root/a`. Each time I run the code, it does nothing inside the container. I can manually create the file, and the container is defined and running during the execution of the code. And also I'm running it as root since I can't access the container otherwise.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lxc/lxccontainer.h>

int lxc_exec(char *prog, char *argv[])
{
  struct lxc_container *c;
  lxc_attach_options_t opt = LXC_ATTACH_OPTIONS_DEFAULT;
  lxc_attach_command_t cmd;
  int ret = -1;
  int status;
  pid_t pid;

  const char *lxc = "/var/lib/container_test/lxc";
  const char *name = "container_test";

  c = lxc_container_new(name, lxc);

  cmd = (lxc_attach_command_t)
    {
      .program = prog,
      .argv = argv
    };

  ret = c->attach(c, lxc_attach_run_command, &cmd, &opt, &pid);

  // this evaluates to true
  if (ret >= 0)
    pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

  return ret;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char program = "/bin/touch";
  char *argv[] = {"/home/a"};
  int ret;

  ret = lxc_exec(program, argv);

  // Returns: Return code is 65280;
  printf("Return code is %d", ret);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've found my answer in the end.

argv also needs to contain the program name. Even if I also tried that, there was another small thing I've missed. There needs to be a NULL element in the array to work.

I've edited my function `lxc_exec` to only accept an char array, and when I'm building the command struct I did:

```
command.program = argv[0];
command.argv = argv;
```

When calling the function it's now been called as

```
char *args[] = {'/bin/touch', '/home/a', NULL};
int ret = lxc_exec(args);
```